# Yearly Report in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting

Hi I'm new in crystal reporting, i would like to make a yearly and monthly report when a button(Yearly Report) is click Yearly Report in crystal report is view.  Should i make a formula? or just in Select Expert using is in the  period as?Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a report parameter called: @ReportingPeriod

This can be a series of text options (Monthly, Weekly, Daily, etc.) or it can be numeric on the order of '# of months' (1, 3, 6, 12)

Then you need to edit the 'Report Selection Criteria...' as a formula and append the following code:

```
(
  ... EXISTING SELECTION CRITIERIA ...
)
AND 
(
    (@ReportingPeriod = "Yearly" && {CreateDate} < '1/1/2014')
        OR
    (@ReportingPeriod = "Monthly" && {CreateDate} < '1/1/2014' && {CreateDate} = '12/1/2014')
)
```

So the parameter you've created becomes the basis for the filter criteria enabling a variety of scenarios depending on the parameters value.

DISCLAIMER: This pseudo code is conceptual and is not valid Crystal Reports formula code.

Comment: can you give me the whole codes for @reportingperiod paramter ? thank you in advance .

Comment: @user3192219 - Please see this video - How to create report parameters in Crystal. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlBECSFW4io